# Call a redux-saga generator function from .map in another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to `yield call` `getdata` generator function from `updateData`, but the method is not getting called.

```
    function* getdata(action) { 
      try {
       let response = yield call(doCall, {
          url: 'https://.....',
          method: GET,
        });
      }catch(e){
      }
    } 
    function* updateData(action) { 
      try {
       let array = ['1', '2', '3'];
         array.map(function* (i){
           return yield call(getdata, { ...action });  // this is not 
                    // calling getdata generator method
        });
      }catch(e){
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not every generator is a saga. For the redux-saga library to process it you need to somehow pass it into the library (like using `call` or `fork`). In this case you can use the array `map` method to create an array of effects that you can then execute using `all` afterwards.

```
function* updateData(action) { 
  try {
    let array = ['1', '2', '3'];
    const effectList = array.map(i => call(getdata, { ...action }));
    const result = yield all(effectList);
  }catch(e){
  }
}
```